# Questions regarding the proof of a physical identity

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is it really on topic to ask questions regarding an exact proof/how to approach the proof of a particular identity, or a physical equation?

Comment: Two things: (1) physics is not math, so proofs are likely not on topic, and (2) questions on 'proving' equations found in undergraduate textbooks will likely be closed as too homework-like.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5473/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7140/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

Simply asking "*How does line X.Z come from line X.Y?*" is likely to get your question closed as [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) (or maybe *unclear* if you don't quote the relevant section of the text/paper you're referring to). So for it to remain open and answered, it needs to be framed to be about the *physics* of what the math is saying, rather than *how* to do the math.<sup>1</sup>

For example, one could ask about the assumptions underlying the derivation, but I think it important to include your expectation of *why* you think something is screwy with the derivation (e.g., *Why do we take the small x limit here, can't x be big because Reason Y?*).

<sup>1. Such a question would likely be on topic over at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).</sup>

Comment: I'm kinda curious what there is to disagree with here.

Comment: Is it the first or the second paragraph that's caused the downvoters to vote as they did? Because, AFAICT, this *is* what actually occurs presently. I'm fine with the disagreement, but would like some clarification (which would only go to help the discourse).